# How to generate a 'cartoon' profile picture

Tags: images, software-recommendation

I'm searching for a generator or method which is used to create the cartoon style profile pictures sometimes seen on GitHub. The effect I want generates a new picture (which looks drawn or painted by the computer) from the original profile picture.

Here is an example of what I want to recreate:

[image: cartoon profile picture]

Comment: Hello MaxC, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Being unfamiliar with GitHub, I had to browse around the site a bit. I can discern no singular trend in avatar whatsoever, unless you count straight photographic images. Please give an example or define the style better. Thanks!

Comment: I think you may have to upload an example, because I'm not sure what you mean. As far as I'm aware GitHub either gives you an [identicon](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=identicon&tbm=isch) or an Image you upload yourself (similar to SE)

Comment: Moreover, we prefer question that show some effort: what software have you tried and why didn't it love up to your expectations? Why are standard programs like Photoshop, Illustrator, GIMP or InkScape not your answers? Please have a look at the [help] for some information on how the site works and how to ask a good question. You can also enter [chat] and ask us directly once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Are you looking for software that you can use on a site, or a tutorial for you to use with something like Photoshop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would just be a vector image. drawn in a program such as Adobe Illustrator. There are tools online that will allow you to build a cartoon profile image—just search for '[Cartoon Profile Picture Generator](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=cartoon%20profile%20picture%20generator)'. But the profile images you see on GitHub are more than likely drawn by hand.